# How to change Symbol Number to Upper Case... in the "richTextBox.Lines" array?

Tags: c#

How to change to Upper Case SymbolNumber... in the "richTextBox.Lines" array?
I have a problem with "ToUpper()", because it is working only with the "String" data, but I need change the case to upper by number of the symbol.

For example...
I have a text...
"qwerty \n
 asdfgh \n
 zxcvbn"
...in the "richTextBox.Text", and I need to change case of symbol #3 in each line (e, d, c) to Upper.

Comment: Could you explain your problem better, please? What have you tried so far? Could you give us also an example of what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what's exactly your situation, but you can expand bellow code for words , ...:

**I:**

```
var strs = richtextbox.Text.Split("\n".ToCharArray());
var items = "";
foreach(var item in strs)
{
   items += new string(item.Select((x,index)=> index == 2?x.ToUpper():x)
                        .ToArray()) 
                        + "\n";
}
```

**Edit:** As I understand from your comment, this would work for you:

indexUpper is input for example set it as 3:

**II:**

```
richTextBox1.Lines = richTextBox1.Lines
                .Where(x => x.Length > indexUpper + 1)
                .Select(s => s.Substring(0,indexUpper) 
                            + s[indexUpper].ToString().ToUpper()
                            + s.Substring(indexUpper,s.Length - indexUpper - 1))
                .ToArray();
```

and if you want to have all items:

**III:**

```
             this.richTextBox1.Lines = richTextBox1.Lines
            //.Where(x => x.Length > indexUpper + 1)
            .Select(s => s.Length > indexUpper + 1? s.Substring(0,indexUpper) 
                        + s[indexUpper].ToString().ToUpper()
                        + s.Substring(indexUpper + 1,s.Length - indexUpper - 1)
                        : s.Length == indexUpper + 1?
                        s.Substring(0,indexUpper) 
                        + s[indexUpper].ToString().ToUpper()
                        :s).ToArray();
```

Comment: Doesn't working. I want similar code... this.richTextBox.Lines = this.richTextBox.Lines.Where(x => x.Length > 0).Select(s => s.ToCharArray(upperCaseSymbol, 1).ToString().ToUpper()).ToArray(); ...but this code doesn't works. (((

Comment: Thank You! This code working...                this.richTextBox.Lines = this.richTextBox.Lines.Where(x => x.Length > 0)
                .Select(s => s.Substring(0, indexUpper-1) + s[indexUpper-1].ToString().ToUpper() + s.Substring(indexUpper, s.Length - indexUpper)).ToArray(); ...but if one of the lines has the quantity of symbols less, than "indexUpper", the program doesn't works. (If I use this code... .Where(x => x.Length > indexUpper + 1) ...the lines has the quantity of symbols less, than "indexUpper", just become removed.

Comment: @user922907, my third answer cover this problem

Comment: Thank You! Resolved. But anyway, I've changed few parts of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string text = "qwerty\nasdfgh\nzxcvbn";
        richTextBox1.Text = text;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //change ever 3rd charater in each line:
        string[] words = richTextBox1.Text.Split(new string[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        richTextBox1.Text = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
        {
            char[] chars = words[i].ToCharArray();
            chars[2] = Convert.ToChar(chars[2].ToString().ToUpper());
            string newWord = new string(chars);
            richTextBox1.AppendText(newWord + "\n");
        }
    }
```

Comment: But if the text in the "richTextBox1" will include not only 1 word in each line and will have 200 lines with different quantity of symbols and words? That was only an example.